# invalid build flag -rw-r--r-- when using esbuild in aws amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify

I am trying to host a nextjs project in aws amplify. as my app size is more than the amplify limit, I had to use the following command to reduce the size of my app during the build

```
- allfiles=$(ls -al ./.next/standalone/**/*.js)
- npx esbuild $allfiles --minify --outdir=.next/standalone --platform=node --target=node16 --format=cjs --allow-overwrite
```

but I got the following error
`Invalid build flag: "-rw-r--r--"`
it seems there is some permission problem but not sure how to fix it.

nextjs version: 12
Node version: 16
amplify cli version: 10.6.2

I'm new to aws, thank you for your help

Comment: What does `ls -al ./.next/standalone/**/*.js` return?  You're getting the file permissions mixed in there.

Answer (score 1):

Although those 2 commands are indicated in the [Amplify Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ssr-deployment.html#build-output-too-large.) , this part of the first command:

```
ls -al ./.next/standalone/**/*.js
```

returns a list of all the .js files in the directory including their file permissions (e.g. -rw-r--r--). The npx esbuild command expects the input to be file paths, but it's receiving the file permissions as well.

Try instead:

```
allfiles=$(ls -1 ./.next/standalone/**/*.js)
```

Answer (score 0):

Made an account specially for this one :)

The suggestion to use `ls` is wrong altogether.

What happens when you install chart.js?

Instead, you can use the xargs command to pass the list of files from the find command directly to esbuild:

`find ./.next/standalone -type f -name "*.js" | xargs npx esbuild --minify --outdir=.next/standalone --platform=node --target=node16 --format=cjs --allow-overwrite"`

For example within the amplify build.yaml

```yaml
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - amplifyPush --simple
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
        - find ./.next/standalone -type f -name "*.js" | xargs npx esbuild --minify --outdir=.next/standalone --platform=node --target=node16 --format=cjs --allow-overwrite


  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```